# PHP - create a tournament results order from array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Consider I have a following array of total scores, with each value being a score of a player in a tournament.

```
$total_scores = array(350,200,150,150,75,75,75,0);
```

I need to create a table, which lists the players with correct positions, if they have the same score, the listing should reflect this, ie.:

```
1.     Player 1     350
2.     Player 2     200
3.-4.  Player 3     150
3.-4.  Player 4     150
5.-7.  Player 5     75
5.-7.  Player 6     75
5.-7.  Player 7     75
8.     Player 8     0
```

I tried to do something with

```
foreach ($total_scores as $total_score) {
        $no_of_occurrences = array_count_values($total_scores)[$total_score];
    }
```

But cannot figure out how to build the correct positions numbering.

Comment: `3.-4.` and so on what it means? is it necessary?

Comment: It's the range of their positions in the ranking. Player 3 and Player 4 each have 150 points thus sharing 3th and 4th place in the ranking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php    
$scores = array(350,200,150,150,75,75,75,0);  //assuming you have sorted data otherwise you need to sort it first
    $count = array();
    $startIndex = array();
    $endIndex = array();
    $len = count($scores);
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
        if(!isset($count[$scores[$i]])){
            $count[$scores[$i]] = 1;
            $startIndex[$scores[$i]] = $endIndex[$scores[$i]] = $i+1;
        }else{
            $count[$scores[$i]]++;
            $endIndex[$scores[$i]] = $i+1;          
        }
    }

    $i = 1;
    foreach($scores as $s){
        echo $startIndex[$s].'.';
        if($startIndex[$s] != $endIndex[$s]){
            echo '-'.$endIndex[$s].'.';
        }
        echo ' Player '.$i.' '.$s."\n";        //if newline not works try echoing <br>
        $i++;
    }
```

[Working Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a44cfed809a03edfd425184f13f1b2bd02293d44)

Comment: Thanks, works great! Some explanation would be helpful though...:-)

Comment: @user1049961 let me know which part you didn't understand..basic idea is I take a value and check if it's already in my count array if it's not then I increment the count as well set the starting and end index for that value...if it appears again i just increment the count and update the end index :)

Answer (score 0):

For this Array needs to be sorted in descending order

```
$total_scores = array(350, 200, 150, 150, 75, 75, 75, 0);
rsort($total_scores);
$no_of_occurrence = array_count_values($total_scores);
array_unshift($total_scores, ""); // For starting count from 1
unset($total_scores[0]); // For starting count from 1
$i = 1;
foreach ($total_scores as $key => $value)
{
    $position = array_keys($total_scores,$value);
    if($no_of_occurrence[$value] == 1)
    {
        echo "Position " . $i . " ";
        echo "Player " . $i . " " . $value . " ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Position " . $position[0] . " - " . end($position) . " ";
        echo "Player " . $i . " " . $value . " ";
    }
    $i++;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output of above code :

```
Position 1 Player 1 350 
Position 2 Player 2 200 
Position 3 - 4 Player 3 150 
Position 3 - 4 Player 4 150 
Position 5 - 7 Player 5 75 
Position 5 - 7 Player 6 75 
Position 5 - 7 Player 7 75 
Position 8 Player 8 0
```